# What is the difference between CQ5 and AEM 6.x? What are the major differences?

Tags: aem, aem-6

When I say CQ5 I mean the version 5.5.

**I would like to know the major differences in features.**

I have seen AEM 6.0, the core of it is the same as CQ5. I checked out the examples, all the examples are the same, the only difference I found was the UI of WCM i.e. there is a new look and feel for it but you can still switch to the classic mode.

CQ5 still encourages coding in JSP i.e. it still uses scriplets.

Is there any alternative to using Scriptlets in AEM 6.x?

I feel Adobe just changed the look and feel of CQ5 and they have released a new version of it called AEM 6.x

**What are the killer features of AEM 6.x that are not there in CQ5 ?**

Comment: Besides yash's answer: With AEM 6 you can also use AEM Forms which is meant to replace Live Cycle. But it is a separate license. They also enhanced many integrations to their Marketing Cloud products like Adobe Campaign.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to take a look for [release notes](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/release-notes.html)

I like below features quite a lot:

- A new repository Apache Jackrabbit Oak.
- Sightly, a new templating language that way you can avoid scriptlet code to a great extent.
- Supporting better user management by delegating the permissions.
- Create projects wizard & project templates

The above ones are very few which I have highlighted. There are many more so as per my opinion its not just UI changes so make sure you go through release notes to learn and then justify accordingly.